# Python - gc.collect() not work. How i can solve?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, del

I am new in python. And i am working big data. And i get MemoryError. I used gc.collect() but is not work. Please help and Thank.

This code is just an example

```
import gc

x=[[0,0],[1,1]]
y=[2,2]
x.append(y)
del x,y
gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can use gc.enable() to automatically collect free lists garbage for memory efficiency, but if you dont want to use it,
You may refer to Official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) and this useful [link](https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/) I found or the good old [GEEKS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/garbage-collection-python/)